# For loop - condition breaking - async function inside

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

Can someone explain to me what is happening to the `for` loop here? I don't understand why the loop goes beyond its' condition. I expect condition `[i]` to stop at '2'. I suppose that this behavior would be same for other async functions inside a `for` loop. Much thanks!

```
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var request = require('request')
var cheerio = require('cheerio')

for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    var arr = []
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'

    request (url, function(error,response,body) {
      if(error){
        throw err;
      } $ = cheerio.load(body)

      var x = $.html()
      console.log(i)
    })
}

/* Results
0
1
2
3
3
3
*/
```

Comment: dry run this condition `for(i=0; i < 3; i++){` if its start from `0` it will run `3` times to run only two times either change `for(i=1; i < 3; i++){` or `for(i=0; i < 2; i++){` or  `for(i=0; i <= 1; i++){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop executes exactly 3 times and logs `i` here - `0,1,2`:

```
for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
    console.log(i)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <--------------------------------
```

But then callback that is added here

```
request(url, function(error,response,body){
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <----------------------------
```

is executed 3 times and logs `3, 3, 3`:

```
    if(error){
        throw err;
    } $ = cheerio.load(body)
        var x = $.html()
        console.log(i)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-----------------------------
    })
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) to understand why `i` is outputted as `3` in the callback three times, instead of `0, 1, 2` as you'd probably expect. If you used `let` instead of `var`, you'd get expected `0, 1, 2`:

```
for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
```

Comment: Thanks Maximus for breaking it down. Actually, I don't expect the function to return "0,1,2" because I know that "i" condition already reached its' maximum by the time async returned any value. I would expect "2, 2, 2". If it  loop executed 3 times, and not 4 times, then why there is ever a "3" ? Thanks for the link. I'll go through it now!

Comment: @user7861743, you're welcome. _I would expect "2, 2, 2"_, no, the `i` counter is to `3` when the loop ends... this is why `i < 3` condition evaluates to `false` and loop is over. Otherwise, if `i` stayed `2`, the loop would never end. Btw, you can accept my answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Maximus tells you why the code is doing what it does. But how do you fix it? The most basic way, if you can use ES6 language features (which you probably can, since it looks like you're using Node.js), is to declare your variables with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var`. `let` behaves in a way that you would probably expect. In addition to behaving more reasonably when referenced from lambdas, variables declared with `let` are block scoped instead of function scoped, which is more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the explanation. I was using self-executing function to go around that issue I was facing, but I tried 'let' and it seems that the output is exactly the same.